# UIViewImage not loading in Subview within a Class method

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, uiview, global-variables

I am trying to load a UIImage View into a tabbar application with a global class, the image doesn't load the image the first time the rootviewcontroler is loaded, but it does show the alert. If you click on another tabbar item  to load another view and come back to the first view the alert and image both show up correctly.

```
#import "globalNetworkCheck.h"

#import "CheckNetworkAvaliblity.h"

#import "ViewController.h"


@implementation globalNetworkCheck



static globalNetworkCheck *getNetworkStatus = nil;

static UIView *viewNetworkError = nil;

+(globalNetworkCheck *)getNetworkStatus
 {
@synchronized(self)
{       if(getNetworkStatus==nil)     {
    // getNetworkStatus= [globalNetworkCheck new];

    if ([CheckNetworkAvaliblity CheckNetwork])
    {
        {
            [(UIView *)viewNetworkError removeFromSuperview];

            viewNetworkError.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];


            viewNetworkError.hidden=YES;


            [viewNetworkError removeFromSuperview];

            [[viewNetworkError subviews]
             makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];


            NSLog(@"Success, Your network is available");
        }
    }
    else
    {

        UIImageView *imgNoConnection = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, 320 , 449)];


        viewNetworkError = [[UIView alloc]init];

        [imgNoConnection setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Noconnection.png"]];

        viewNetworkError.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320 , 449);

        [viewNetworkError addSubview: imgNoConnection];

        viewNetworkError.hidden = NO;

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.view addSubview:viewNetworkError];

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle: @"Connection Failed"
                              message: @"You are not connected to the internet. Please check your network settings and try again."
                              delegate: self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

        viewNetworkError.hidden = NO;

        NSLog(@"Sorry, Network connection is unavailable");
    }}}

return getNetworkStatus;

}

@end
```

I am calling the class method on

```
     -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    globalNetworkCheck *obj=[globalNetworkCheck getNetworkStatus];
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
[viewNetworkError addSubview:viewNetworkError];
```

Strange to me, how are you going to add `viewNetworkError` to `viewNetworkError`.

**Edit**

I think you mean

```
 [self addSubview:viewNetworkError];
```

Comment: Once I do that the image doesn't appear like it needs to.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need somewhere to add the view. Right now this class method has no association on the view hierarchy. If you want to keep it a class method like this then you'll either need to add your error views to the window or the root view controllers view.

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.view addSubview:viewNetworkError];`
or
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:viewNetworkError];`

Without understanding the full view stack it is a bit hard to answer further. Alternatively with more rework you can put this responsibility on the AppDelegate rather than a class method like this. Create a view that your App delegate can add to the hierarchy as needed, create a public getter on your app delegate to check current network status, etc. Here is an example of how to great a HUD type view:
http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/ios-code-tweetbot-like-alertpanels/

Comment: I am getting the image to appear now it just dismisses itself. Any suggestions.

Comment: what dismisses itself? the alert view? You've got NSLogs in both case, do those fire?

Comment: I moved the [alert show]; to the bottom of the method. It doesn't dismiss it's self anymore it just doesn't load the image on the first rootviewcontroler the time it is loaded, but it does show the alert. but if you click on another tabbar item and come back the alert and image both show up correctly. I have edited the code above to show you what I have.

Comment: It's really hard to say how to help further without seeing the whole app. It sounds like something in your view controller stack is funky. You can try adding right to the window (I'll adjust my answer)